# Repaint in Panel method not updated

Tags: java, swing, timer, jpanel, actionlistener

I am trying to make a program that work like this:
In Window class every time I click on the button, the method panel2 of Panel is called: first it is drawing a first circle, then a second one (after the time defined in the timer). Then, I click again on the button, and it is drawing a fist circle, then a second one then a third one. etc.
The problem is that it when I click to obtain 3 circles appearing one after the other, the two first circles drawn at the previous step (before I pressed a second time the button) stay on the screen and only the third circle is drawn when i press the button (instead of having : first circle drawn, second circle drawn, third circle drawn). I hope I am clear.
Here is a simple code:

**Window**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Window extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    int h = 2;

    Panel b = new Panel();
    JPanel container = new JPanel();

    JButton btn = new JButton("Start");
    JButton bouton = new JButton();


    Panel boutonPane = new Panel();

    public Window(){

        this.setTitle("Animation");
        this.setSize(300, 300);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        container.setBackground(Color.white);
        container.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel top = new JPanel();

        btn.addActionListener(this);
        top.add(btn);
        container.add(top);
        this.setContentPane(container);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void window2(){
        this.setTitle("ADHD");
        this.setSize(1000,700);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);


        if (h < 11){

            boutonPane.panel2(h);
            bouton.addActionListener(this);
            boutonPane.add(bouton);
            this.add(boutonPane);
            this.setContentPane(boutonPane);
            updateWindow2();
        }
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void updateWindow2(){
        boutonPane.panel2(h);
        this.revalidate();
        this.repaint();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if ((JButton) e.getSource() == btn){
            System.out.println("pressed0");
            window2();
        }
        if ((JButton) e.getSource() == bouton){
            h++;
            System.out.println("pressed" + h);
            updateWindow2();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Window w = new Window();
    }
}
```

**Panel**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;


public class Panel extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

    int m;
    int u=0;
    int lgi, lrgi;
    int [] ta;
    Timer timer1 = new Timer(300, this);

    Panel(){

    }

    public void panel2(int n){
        m=n;
        ta = new int [n];

        for(int it=0; it<m;it++){
            ta[it]=100*it;
        }

        timer1.start();
    }


    public void paintComponent(Graphics gr){
        super.paintComponent(gr);

        gr.setColor(Color.red);
        for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
            gr.fillOval(ta[i],ta[i], 150, 150);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        if(u<m){
            u++;
            revalidate();
            repaint();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: If your program generates an error, you should post that error message for all to see.

Comment: Also: Please learn and follow Java naming conventions. Method and variable names should start with a lower-case letter. Also give your variables names that have meaning. It's hard to know what variable `ta`, or `u`, or `lg` represent.

Comment: Also, when iterating through an array with a for loop, use the array's length field in your condition statement to decide how many times to loop. Your current code uses an int variable, `u`, unrelated to the length of the `ta` array, causing your code to throw a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException from a for loop.

Comment: @peeskillet -- where did your answer go? Where did my up-vote of your answer go?

Comment: @Hovercraft -- I corrected everything of what you told me. For the variable `u` I put this one because it make the paintComponent repaint with the current variable in the actionPerformed (since I only an paint in the paintComponent).

Comment: But when I ran your code, I ran up against an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException because of your use of this `u` variable. Myself, I'd create a `List<Ellipse2D>` objects and then would iterate through the List in the paintComponent method, painting each ellipse. I'd also recommend that you follow @peeskillet's good advice, not to keep re-adding ActionListeners to your bouton JButton.

Comment: And now your code won't compile for me.

Comment: I don't think I keep re-adding ActionListeners. Look carefully the code and how it is working. The function is called only once.

Comment: OK, sorry, my bad. But please fix your code so that it now compiles for me.

Comment: Thanks. Now one more time, please explain 1) what the current code is doing that you don't want it to do and 2) what it's not doing that you want it to do.

Comment: I write what I want and you'll understand what I don't want. I want I press on `btn` and it is drawing one circle, 300ms (time defined in the timer) nothing, then it is drawing a second circle (the first remain). Then I press on `bouton` and it is doing the same with 3 circles (first circle is drawn, 300ms, second one is drawn (with the previous that remain), 300ms, third one is drawn (...). And then for 4 cicles, etc until 11.

Comment: I haven't answered yet because I am still trying to understand where I should put each function and make them interact between Window and Panel. I have understand the principle of the code but not how I should organize it.

Comment: Please see edit to answer for an example.

Comment: What is the point to use a `JButton` with `MNEMONIC_KEY` through `ButtonAction`?

Comment: The AbstractAction, Action, JButton, and AbstractButton API's explain all of this as do the tutorials. I invite you to read them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code needs use two int values to decide how many circles to draw and when:

- The first int should be the count of current circles to draw, say called, `currentCirclesToDraw`.
- The second int will be the number of circles to draw total.
- If you use a `List<Ellipse2D>` like I suggest, then this number will be the size of the list. So if the List is called `ellipseList`, then the 2nd number will be `ellipseList.size()`.
- The first variable will be incremented in the timer up to the size of the list, but no larger, and will be used by paintComponent method to decide how many circles to draw.
- Key point here: the first number, the `currentCirclesToDraw`, **must** be re-set to 0 when the button is pressed. This way your paintComponent method will start out drawing 0 circles, then 1, then 2, ...

For example, the paintComponent method could look like so:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
  super.paintComponent(g);
  Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
  g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
        RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
  g2.setColor(CIRCLE_COLOR);
  for (int i = 0; i < currentCirclesToDraw && i < ellipseList.size(); i++) {
     g2.fill(ellipseList.get(i));
  }
}
```

I use the second term in the for loop conditional statement,  `i < currentCirclesToDraw && i < ellipseList.size()` as an additional fail-safe to be sure that we don't try to draw more circles then we have in our list.

My Timer's ActionListener would increment the currentCirclesToDraw variable and call repaint. It would stop the Timer once currentCirclesToDraw reaches the size of the ellipseList:

```
private class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     if (currentCirclesToDraw < ellipseList.size()) {
        currentCirclesToDraw++;
        repaint();
     } else {
        // stop the Timer
        ((Timer)e.getSource()).stop();
     }
  }
}
```

And my button's actionPerformed method would reset currentCirclesToDraw to 0, would add a new Ellipse2D to my ellipseList (if we've not yet reached the MAX_CIRCLE_INDEX), would call `repaint()` to clear the JPanel, and would construct and start the Timer:

```
  public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent arg0) {
     currentCirclesToDraw = 0;  // this is key -- reset the index used to control how many circles to draw
     if (ellipseList.size() < MAX_CIRCLE_INDEX) {
        double x = (ellipseList.size()) * CIRCLE_WIDTH / Math.pow(2, 0.5);
        double y = x;
        double w = CIRCLE_WIDTH;
        double h = CIRCLE_WIDTH;
        ellipseList.add(new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, w, h));
     }
     repaint(); // clear image
     new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, new TimerListener()).start();
  };
```

---

**Edit** 3/30/14
Note it all can be put together like this:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.*;

/**
 * http://stackoverflow.com/a/22714405/522444
 * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22712655/repaint-in-panel-method-not-updated
 * @author Pete
 *
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TimerCircles extends JPanel {
   private static final int PREF_W = 1000;
   private static final int PREF_H = 700;
   private static final Color CIRCLE_COLOR = Color.RED;
   public static final int MAX_CIRCLE_INDEX = 11;
   public static final int TIMER_DELAY = 300;
   public static final int CIRCLE_WIDTH = 100;
   private final List<Ellipse2D> ellipseList = new ArrayList<>();
   private int currentCirclesToDraw = 0;

   public TimerCircles() {
      add(new JButton(new ButtonAction("New Circle", KeyEvent.VK_C)));
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
      g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
      g2.setColor(CIRCLE_COLOR);
      for (int i = 0; i < currentCirclesToDraw && i < ellipseList.size(); i++) {
         g2.fill(ellipseList.get(i));
      }
   }

   private class ButtonAction extends AbstractAction {
      public ButtonAction(String name, int mnemonic) {
         super(name);
         putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
      }

      public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent arg0) {
         currentCirclesToDraw = 0;  // this is key -- reset the index used to control how many circles to draw
         if (ellipseList.size() < MAX_CIRCLE_INDEX) {
            double x = (ellipseList.size()) * CIRCLE_WIDTH / Math.pow(2, 0.5);
            double y = x;
            double w = CIRCLE_WIDTH;
            double h = CIRCLE_WIDTH;
            ellipseList.add(new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, w, h));
         }
         repaint(); // clear image
         new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, new TimerListener()).start();
      };
   }

   private class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         if (currentCirclesToDraw < ellipseList.size()) {
            currentCirclesToDraw++;
            repaint();
         } else {
            // stop the Timer
            ((Timer)e.getSource()).stop();
         }
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      TimerCircles mainPanel = new TimerCircles();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("TimerCircles");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```